# What are the scenarios when Worker of Google's Android WorkManager can enter the CANCELLED state?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Recently, started using the WorkManager library.
1)If I cancel a tagged work using it's tag, does it enter the CANCELLED state?
2)What are other scenarios can make it go to CANCELLED state?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like only a manual cancellation of a worker results in it being in the `CANCELLED` state (or by the system).

It does not matter which `Result` is returned in `doWork()`.

---

I think it's the same as when `onStopped()` is called:

> https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#onstopped
>
> This method is invoked when this Worker has been told to stop. This could happen due to an explicit cancellation signal by the user, or because the system has decided to preempt the task. In these cases, the results of the work will be ignored by WorkManager.